# Play sound without onClickListener

Tags: android

How can I play a sound in an activity without requiring the press of a button? I already know how to play the sound, but need to bypass the onClickListener. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could tell the sound to play in onStart() or onResume(), which are methods of Activity inherited by your subclass.